# Can I use unique index in GROUP BY clause instead of column in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, index

I have a table **shift_wise_traffic** with following columns.

```
toll        date            shift      car      truck      bus
 1          2016-09-01        1        10        20        30
 1          2016-09-01        2        15        25        35
 1          2016-09-01        3        20        30        40

 2          2016-09-01        1        5         10        15
 2          2016-09-01        2        20        25        30
 2          2016-09-01        3        35        40        50

 1          2016-09-02        1        10        20        30
 1          2016-09-02        2        10        20        30
 1          2016-09-02        3        10        20        30

 2          2016-09-02        1        10        20        30
 2          2016-09-02        2        10        20        30
 2          2016-09-02        3        10        20        30
```

Now I want to produce the output from **shift_wise_traffic** table group by
**toll**, **date**. And I have created a unique-index named **shift_unique_index** having two columns **toll** and **date**.

so instead of writing following query,

```
SELECT toll, date, SUM(car), SUM(truck), SUM(bus) FROM shift_wise_traffic 
GROUP BY toll, date;
```

Can I use this query using **shift_unique_index**,

```
SELECT toll, date, SUM(car), SUM(truck), SUM(bus) FROM shift_wise_traffic 
GROUP BY shift_unique_index;
```

Comment: Why do you think you need that?

Comment: Based on the sample data, `UNIQUE(toll, date)` would _not_ work.  There are 3 rows for each combination of `(toll, date)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT toll, date, SUM(car), SUM(truck), SUM(bus)
    FROM shift_wise_traffic 
    GROUP BY toll, date;
```

- The `GROUP BY` must have a list of *columns*, not an index name.
- An `INDEX` is an optimization, *not* a requirement.
- An `INDEX` *may* be useful for queries like this.  (No index is likely to be useful for *this* particular query.)
- Probably this query will simply scan the entire table, sort by toll+date, sum up the values, then deliver the output.  (Or it may build an in-memory hash based on toll+date for summing.)
- `UNIQUE` versus `INDEX` -- makes no difference in this context.  `UNIQUE` = `INDEX` + a constraint.  For `INSERT`, `UNIQUE` prevents duplicates.

It feels like your `PRIMARY KEY` is `(date, shift, toll)` in some order.  Is it?  If so, then changing the order to `PRIMARY KEY(toll, date, shift)` *might* make your `GROUP BY` run a little faster.  (But it might slow down other operations.)

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are part[1] of the physical model. The query language which we normally refer to as SQL (correct would be DML) is not aware of indexes, they should be transparent to the application. In fact, indexes are not even mentioned in the standard. Now, this is only true to some extent since a unique index violation definitely will have an affect on how the query is evaluated.

To make a long history short, you can't address an index in a query the way you suggests. It is a job for the optimizer to pick a decent access plan for the query. That said vendors provide different mechanisms to influence the optimizer to choose another plan that it would otherwise. In your case:

```
SELECT toll, date, SUM(car), SUM(truck), SUM(bus) 
FROM shift_wise_traffic USE INDEX (shift_unique_index)
GROUP BY toll, date;
```

However, hints should be the last resort in tricky cases where nothing else helps and the optimizer can't figure out a decent plan. Having hints in the code means that you may have to change the code as data grows or shrinks.

Things to investigate:

Look at the plan, does it or does it not use the index. If it does not, should it use the index or is it cheaper to scan the table (do you have a realistic amount of data in the table)?

[1] I think SQL server can actually reference columns in unique indexes in foreign keys, but this is a deviation from the standard.

Comment: "*I think SQL server can actually reference indexes in foreign keys*" - to be precise: it allows to reference the _columns_ of a unique index as part of a foreign key. Conceptually this references the (implied) _unique constraint_ defined by the index, not actually the index. Other DBMS (e.g. Postgres or Oracle) can do that as well

Comment: Yes you are correct, I reworded the note. At the same time we normally say that we reference the primary or unique constraint, when it is the columns defined in the constraint we use in the foreign key.